# JAGS - apply function to all parameter nodes

Tags: r, syntax, jags, winbugs, r2jags

I'm new to JAGS and I'm running a model in R via `R2jags` package.
The model code is based on a code taken from Kéry & Schaub 2012 ('Bayesian Population Analysis using WinBUGS"), pg 399.

Chi-square discrepancy measure is computed

```
model { 
....
for(g in 1:G) {
  for (t in 1:T) {
    ...
    E[g,t] <- pow((y[g,t] - eval[g,t]),2) / eval[g,t]
    ...
  }#t
}#g

fit <- sum(E[,])

}#model
```

where `g` and `t` are site and time indices and `G` and `T` are then the number of sites and the number of years

I get an error though

```
Error in jags.model(model.file, data = data, inits = init.values, n.chains = n.chains,  : 
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 140.
Cannot evaluate subset expression for fit
```

Is it caused by different syntax used by JAGS relative to WinBUGS? The code is the same used in the book, except for I have 2 dimensions instead of three as in the book example.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question, no that error isn't caused by different syntax in JAGS (although the error message might look different in BUGS).

In fact I can't see anything wrong with the code snippet that you have posted, and the following reproducible example shows that it works at least when y and eval are given in data:

```
m <- 'model { 
for(g in 1:G) {
  for (t in 1:T) {
    E[g,t] <- pow((y[g,t] - eval[g,t]),2) / eval[g,t]
  }#t
}#g

fit <- sum(E[,])

#data# G, T, y, eval
#monitor# fit

}#model
'

library('runjags')

G=T <- 10
y <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=G, ncol=T)
eval <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=G, ncol=T)

results <- run.jags(m)
```

Have you verified what line 140 refers to?  Either line 140 is something that you haven't shown, or maybe you have specified either fit or E somewhere else in the model with a different number of dimensions?

If this isn't the case and you still get an error then please add a minimal reproducible example to your question that shows the problem (preferably underneath an ---EDIT--- line below what you have already written) and we can try to help with that.

Matt

Comment: Thank you Matt, the line 140 is the `fit <- sum(E[,])` shown in the code, I didn't specified it sorry! I'll try with a minimum reproducible example then